# Bitwise operations and masking in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

So I'm having trouble trying to isolate a certain amount of bits through masking. Essentially I have a certain amount of bits I want to mask (let's call it offset) from a single byte (so 8 bits). There are 2 kinds of masks I need help with:

First one: say the offset = 4 and I have a byte with binary 1110 0001. I want to mask the *last* bits of size offset such that I can have a final byte of 1110 0000 (so mask the last 4 bits).

Second one: say the offset is 3 and I have a byte with binary 1011 0010. I want to now mask the *first* few bits of size offset so that I have a final byte of 0001 0010.

I've pasted the code I have so far. Currently it does not work for the first mask I want to create as it masks the first few bits not the last. I'm not sure if I'm creating the mask correctly.

```
uint8_t mask = (1 << offset) - 1;
byte = (byte & mask);
```

Comment: You need to position the mask's bits `uint8_t mask = ((1 << offset) - 1) << pos;` and use the complement of mask (~mask) to clear the masked bits from the byte `byte = (byte & ~mask);` .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, please. -- Would you mind to provide a [example]? Or at least some specific examples of `offset` and and mask you expect from it? Like: `offset = 3` gives `mask = 00011110` (setting the left 3 bits to 0, keep the next 4 bits, set the rightmost bit to 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mask off the low `offset` bits, your computation for `mask` is OK, but the expression is not. It should be:

```
byte = (byte & ~mask);
```

or simply:

```
byte &= ~mask;
```

To compute a mask from an offset with `(1 << offset) - 1`, you should beware that offset must be less than the number of bits in the type of `1`. `1` being an `int`, if means `offset < 32`, so you cannot compute the mask for a 32-bit field this way.

Furthermore, even `31` poses a problem because `(1 << 31)` exceeds the range of type `int`. To avoid this, you should write `(1U << offset) - 1` and you must first test if `offset < 32`.

A better alternative that works for `offset` values from `1` to `32` is this:

```
unsigned mask = ~0U >> (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - offset);
bits &= ~mask;
```

or simpler with an opposite mask:

```
bits &= ~0U << offset;
```

Here are macros to get, clear and set a bitfield in an `unsigned int`:

```c
#define GET_MASK(width)               (~0U >> (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - (width)))
#define GET_FIELD(x, pos, width)      (((x) >> (pos)) & GET_MASK(x, width))
#define CLEAR_FIELD(x, pos, width)    (((x) &= ~(GET_MASK(x, width) << (pos)))
#define SET_FIELD(x, pos, width, val) ((x) = ((x) & ~(GET_MASK(x, width) << (pos))) | ((val) << (pos)))
```